# libpqxx как установить?

Tags: c++, windows, postgresql, libpq

Я в `гитхабе` скачал версию библиотеки `7.1.2`.

В `документации` ничего не понятно как скомпилировать библиотеку на `Windows 10`. В интернете тоже ничего не нашел(

Всё что я сделал это скачал библиотеку, про компилирование и подключение ничего еще не знаю(

Вообщем, мне нужно узнать: как скомпилировать и подключить `libpqxx`?

`Желательно, но не обязательно: пример кода подключения к локальной базе данных и выполнения одного запроса.`

Answer (score 0):

Скачиваете и устанавливаете `postgresql` пакет. Вызываете `cmake ..` из директории `build`, которую создаёте в корневой директории библиотеки. Если не хватает каких-то пакетов - доставляете (мне хватило только `postgresql`). Получаете файл `libpqxx-7.2.a`, который линуете со своим приложением с помощью `-l`.

Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        pqxx::connection C;
        std::cout << "Connected to " << C.dbname() << std::endl;
        pqxx::work W{C};

        pqxx::result R{W.exec("SELECT name FROM employee")};

        std::cout << "Found " << R.size() << "employees:\n";
        for (auto row: R)
            std::cout << row[0].c_str() << '\n';

        std::cout << "Doubling all employees' salaries...\n";
        W.exec0("UPDATE employee SET salary = salary*2");

        std::cout << "Making changes definite: ";
        W.commit();
        std::cout << "OK.\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception const &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ты Windows с линукс не спутал? Я на Visual Studio пишу. И как на Виндовс пакет установить? Postgresql у меня установлен с официального сайта. Там в папке библиотека libpq. А как мне libpqxx установить?